# SQL Query Select Clause, need a solution to not return few rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a column in a static table like this:

```
Vehicles  
-------------
Bike  
Truck  
car_2018  
car_2019  
car_2020  
car_2021  
Bus
```

The select query needs to fetch only the car row based on the year of query (for example now its 2018, if I run this next year, it should get back _2019) long with the rest of the rows that's not based on years. Need a solution for this.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT Vehicles 
FROM VehicleMaster 
WHERE 'some where clause based on other columns'
```

Comment: try solving this using regex based search in mysql. check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 2):

```
select Vehicles 
from table_name
where Vehicles like '%2018'
union all 
select Vehicles 
from table_name
where Vehicles not like '%car%'
```

Comment: What about 'caravan'?

Comment: You could use the `year` function to make the year dynamic. For example: `where Vehicles like concat('%', year(now()))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring_index` to split that field by underscore `_` and query based on that:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles(f1 varchar(30));
INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES ('Bike'),
('Truck'),
('car_2018'),
('car_2019'),
('car_2020'),
('car_2021'),
('Bus');

SELECT f1
FROM vehicles
WHERE 
  f1 NOT LIKE 'car%'
  OR (f1 LIKE 'car%' AND substring_index(f1, "_", -1) = YEAR(CURDATE()));

+----------+
|    f1    |
+----------+
| Bike     |
| Truck    |
| car_2018 |
| Bus      |
+----------+
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4a354/4)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to exclude all car_#### rows, except for the current year. Assuming that your Vehicles column is called `name`, this should work for you:

```
select *
from Vehicles
where
  (
    -- Exclude all car_####
    not trim(name) REGEXP '^car_[0-9]{4}$'
    -- Except for the current year
    or name = concat('car_', year(now()))
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.vehicle = concat('car_', year(curdate())) or
      t.vehicle not regexp '[0-9]{4}$'
```

If you want a general purpose "any current year or any without a year", then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.vehicle like concat('%_', year(curdate())) or
      t.vehicle not regexp '[0-9]{4}$'
```